# If $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are positive numbers such that $A + 2B + 3C + 4D = 8$, then what is the maximum value of $ABCD$?

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

If $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are positive numbers such that $A + 2B + 3C + 4D = 8$, then what is the maximum value of $ABCD$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1/2? i bet 1/2 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By A.M.-G.M.,

$$ 8=A+2B+3C+4D\ge4\sqrt[4]{A(2B)(3C)(4D)}$$

$$24ABCD\le2^4$$

$$ABCD\le\frac{2}{3}$$

The equality holds when $A=2B=3C=4D=2$.

The maximum value is $\frac{2}{3}$